# Cannot find kbase, either it is not exist or there are multiple default kbases in kmodule.xml

Tags: drools, complex-event-processing, kie, drools-fusion

I am using Kie workbench 6.3.0 to create rules.
I am using kie server runtime.
I have created project in kie-wb and added kie-base, packages and have set to stream mode from Project Editor.
Following is the kmodule.xml generated:

```
<kmodule xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <kbase name="myKieBase" default="false" eventProcessingMode="stream" equalsBehavior="identity" packages="*"/>
</kmodule>
```

While deploying project it is giving the following error:

```
Deployment of unit com.sample.SampleBusinessRules:2.7 failed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find kbase, either it is not exist or there are multiple default kbases in kmodule.xml
```

Please help me to solve this error.
Thank you

Comment: Are you using your own runtime? Are you using the kie-server to run your kie-bases? How are you creating your kie-base in the first place (if you are not using kie-server)? How does your kcontext.xml file look like?

Comment: Add detail/code to your question.

Comment: Thanks Esteban and Naved for your response. We are using Kie server runtime. I am creating Kie-base using kie-workbench. @Esteban Did you meant by kcontext.xml as kmodule.xml?

Comment: If you want kmodule.xml file content then it is as follows
<kmodule xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <kbase name="myKieBase" default="false" eventProcessingMode="stream" equalsBehavior="identity" packages="*"/>
</kmodule>
The content is automatically generated in the file in kie-wb from Project Editor when we create kie-base and packages and set stream mode to the project.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant kmodule.xml. When is this error exactly happening? Have you tried having 1 default kie-base in your kmodule.xml?

Comment: Thank you Esteban for sparing your time for this issue.
I have resolved this issue. :-)

Comment: By adding these tags in my kmodule.xml
<kmodule xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <kbase name="defaultKieBase" default="true" eventProcessingMode="stream" equalsBehavior="identity" packages="*">
    <ksession name="defaultKieSession" type="stateful" default="true" clockType="realtime" scope="javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped"/>
    <ksession name="defaultStatelessKieSession" type="stateless" default="true" clockType="realtime" scope="javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped"/>
  </kbase>
</kmodule>

Comment: @EstebanAliverti  can you help me with this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39209152/error-calling-container-kiecontainer

Comment: where to create Kie-base using kie-workbench? cant find it.

Answer (score 3):

By adding these tags in my kmodule.xml my issue resolved.

```
 <kmodule xmlns="jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule"; xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">; 
    <kbase name="defaultKieBase" default="true" eventProcessingMode="stream" equalsBehavior="identity" packages="*"> 
      <ksession name="defaultKieSession" type="stateful" default="true" clockType="realtime" scope="javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped"/> 
<ksession name="defaultStatelessKieSession" type="stateless" default="true" clockType="realtime" scope="javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped"/> </kbase> 
    </kmodule>
```

Comment: Where have you find this configuration, Please add a reference